# Thought regarding Newton's law of cooling

Tags: thermodynamics, electromagnetic-radiation, temperature

I learnt that when a body cools by a small temperature say 5-10 k, from T1 to T2 we can approximately write rate of decrease in temp as c ((T1+T2)/2 - To) c is a constant
To representing surrounding temperature
But as this is only an approximation it works only for small changes
However can we insert n arithmetic mean  in between T1 and T2 and apply this approximation for each interval
and then Sum up the times taken for each interval and then substitute n---> infinity to get a final answer for time taken to decrease from T1 to T2 even for large decrease in temp.
I tried doing it but the expression was a bit complicated and as i am only a high school student I'm not sure how to transform summation to integration properly.
But i have a feeling by doing this i will end back up in the original Newton's law of cooling where the expression comes inside natural log and works for any decrease in temp.But I'm hoping the expression derived from my method will be easier to use than the one obtained from Newton's law of cooling containing nasty exponential equations
Can I get some insight on this approach? Thank you!

Comment: The exponential equation is much easier to work with, and is easier on the brain when you are used to it. The infinite amounts of approximation you were trying to do, that thing is much more complicated!

Comment: thanks! i should probably not waste time thinking abt these random thoughts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that $c$ (which you call "a constant") is a function of the temperature. And you cant predict $c$ unless you know a lot of stuff about how the heat capacity and thermal conductivity change with temperature.  This is actually the whole point of the approximation - if the temperature changes by a very small amount, then $c$ changes by a very small amount, and you can approximate it as a constant (which you might determine empirically instead of trying to predict it). But if the temperature change is big, then $c$ is not constant at all.

This is similar to saying "$f(x)$ can be approximated as $f(x)\approx f(x_0)+f'(x_0)(x-x_0)$ for $x$ close to $x_0$". Then $f'(x_0)$ plays the role of $c$ in Newton's cooling law. But the entire function $f$ can't be reconstructed until you know how $f'$ changes with $x_0$. You seem to be thinking $c$ is the same for all small temperature differences regardless of what the temperature is. This is like assuming all functions have constant $f'(x_0)$.

If you follow the procedure you are implying, assuming $c$ truly is constant, I believe you'll end up recovering the same exponential decay of temperature and the same Newton's law of cooling for $dT/dt$, but now the temperature difference will be large instead of small.

Comment: Oh i didn't think of it like that, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you are talking about is numerically integrating the differential equation $$\frac{dT}{dt}=-k(T-T_0)$$ using a so-called central difference approximation to write $$T(t+\Delta t)=T(t)-k\left[\frac{T(t+\Delta t)+T(t)}{2}-T_0)\right]\Delta t$$The solution to this finite difference equation applied successively approaches that of the actual differential equation as $\Delta t$ is made smaller and smaller.